# What does "an algorithm is $\Theta(f(n))$ in the average case" implies?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science

Let $f(n)$ be a positive increasing function. Consider the below two statements:

- S1: if an algorithm is $\Theta(f(n))$ in the average case, then it is $\Omega(f(n))$ in the worst case.
- S2: if an algorithm is $\Theta(f(n))$ in the average case, then it is $O(f(n))$ in the best case. Here $O$ is Big-oh.

Let $g(n)$ represent the number of comparisons required in the algorithm (or the time taken). Then does the statement “algorithm is $\Theta(f(n))$ in the average case” means $g(n) = \Theta(f(n))$  **or** $\Theta(g(n)) = \Theta(f(n))$ **or** $g(n) = \Theta(\Theta(f(n)))$ **or** something else entirely?

Can anyone explain it using the standard definition of asymptotic notations? I know both the statements are true but I’d really appreciate if anyone could help me understand it mathematically.

Also, $g(n) = \Theta(f(n))$ actually means $g(n)$ belongs to the set $\Theta(f(n))$, right?

Comment: Could an example be of help or do you want the formal definition only?

Comment: @b00nheT Of course if it could explain the statements correctly. I know the basic definitions but I'm not sure if I'm applying/inferring it correctly.

Comment: Let me type the answer then.

Comment: Are you working with randomized algorithms? That's what the wording suggests to me. For example, if you have a random algorithm that has a running time $r(n)$ satisfying $cf(n)\le r(n) \le Cf(n)$ in the *average case,* then in the worst case, it would satisfy $r(n)\ge cf(n)$, for example.

Comment: As Alex said, it’s expectation of run time. When analyzing merge sort for example, you analyze how many levels there are (log n) and how much steps at each level (n steps). But this is deterministic. However, in a randomized algorithm as quicksort, you generally look at the expected number of steps (whatever steps means in the context)

Comment: @AlexOrtiz I randomly stumbled upon this question and got confused. But now that you've mentioned about randomized algorithms it totally makes sense.

Comment: The subtlety is about what you're averaging over: is it the average performance of a randomized algorithm on the worst possible input, or the average performance of a deterministic algorithm on a random input, or the average performance of a randomized algorithm on a random input?

Answer (score 1):

In Informatics one usually wants to know the runtime/speed of an algorithm based on the size of the input. This is the "time complexity"

This is usually defined with the $\Theta$ and the ${O}$ notation. Let's considera an input size $n$ (for large $n$) then saying that an algorithm is:

- $\Theta(n)$ will mean that if you triple the size the algorithm will take  (more or less) triple the time.
- $\Theta(n^2)$ then tripling the size will take the algorithm 9-times as much time to run.
- ${O}(n^2)$ then tripling the size will take the algorithm not more than 9-times as much time to run.

For example $n\log(n)={O}(n^2)$ whereas $n^2+\sqrt{n}=\theta(n^2)$.

Indeed the correct notation is $g(n)=\Theta(f(n))$ and you have to interpret it as a property ``$g(n)$ is asymptotically as $f(n)$'', that can be seen as g(n) is in the set of functions with the $\Theta(f(n))$ property.

---

That said, algorithm performance can vary depending on the input. For example

- sorting using **Selection Sort** takes always the same time $\Theta(n^2)$, this is independent of the input form
- In a **Binary search** it can take just one step $O(1)$ to find the minimum, but on average it will take the algorithm $O(n\log(n))$ time.

Obviously if your average time has a certain time complexity $\text{mean}(n)=\Theta(g(n))$, the best case can't be worse so and the worse case can't be better.

With an abuse of notation you could write $\text{best}(n)\leq \Theta(g(n))$ which in correct notation has to be written $\text{best}(n)=O(g(n))$.

Analogously you get $\text{worst}(n)\geq \Theta(g(n))$ which is written $\text{worst}(n)=\Omega(g(n))$ and this is what the two statements are saying.

Comment: This completely avoids the OPs question. Sorry, I shouldn’t say completely avoids. But I do think you should add some information about that we are talking about randomized algorithm.

Comment: I tried rewriting it to answer to the OP question. Please feel free to post an answer as well. Cheers